# MergeSort Algorithm with Object Classes

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

I have been trying to figure out this thing in the past hours but with no success.

I have several classes which I am using to add data, and so I can display them, but now i have to implement a MergeSort algorithem to sort this datas depending on the titles.

I have the Object CD, which all other classes inherits from, and object CD has the property title, type char.

Now when i pass the pointer to my class I do the comparision and checking, but it's not working how it should:

This is my Function for the Sorting Algorithm:

```
void merge(CD *a[], int, int, int);

void merge_sort(CD *a[], int low, int high) {
    int mid;
    if (low < high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        merge_sort(a, low, mid);
        merge_sort(a,mid + 1, high);
        merge(a, low, mid, high);
    }
}

void merge(CD *a[], int low, int mid, int high) {
    int h, i, j, k;
    CD *b;
    h = low;
    i = low;
    j = mid + 1;


    while ((h <= mid) && (j <= high)) {
        if (a[h]->title[100] <= a[j]->title[100]) {
            b[i].title[100] = a[h]->title[100];
            h++;
        }
        else {
            b[i].title[100] = a[j]->title[100];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (h > mid) {
        for (k = j; k <= high; k++) {
            b[i].title[100] = a[k]->title[100];
            i++;
        }
    }
    else {
        for (k = h; k <= mid; k++) {
            b[i].title[100] = a[k]->title[100];
            i++;
        }
    }
    for (k = low; k <= high; k++) 
        a[k]->title[100] = b[k].title[100];
}
```

Any idea how to implement something like this ?

Comment: title[100]? Can you show us the definition of object CD?

Comment: Here:

class CD
{
    public:
    string publisher, location, year, empty;
     CD();
     void virtual input()=0;
     void virtual output()=0;
            char title[100];
    };

Comment: You can't access the member variable like `.title[100]`, `title[100]` means the 101st of the array `title`, it's out of bounds.

Comment: hmm, i think i changed it a bit, i have used the string type for the variable.

The thing that its not working for me its that i cant access the values, i cant make comparisons with them, and i cant assign the values to another thing etc. 

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Another ***HUGE*** problem that is lurking under there is that you are writing stuff into 'b' without allocating any memory for it. If effect, you are writing your "sorted" data into thin air; not only it vanishes and you won't find it again, but it also overwrites some random stuff in your address space. I'm surprised that your code doesn't crash every time you run it (specially in debug mode/optimizations disabled.)

Comment: Also, definitely add the declaration of `CD` to the question.

Comment: Even i allocated memory, when i try to run the sort its breaking down:

here is my main.cpp:

http://codepad.org/5O4QnUbf

Comment: And the cd.h and cd.cpp

http://codepad.org/xlgWYd2Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several faults in the code you post on [codepad](http://codepad.org/5O4QnUbf), I'll point out in the program comments. Since you didn't give us the definitions of `Popular`, `Symphony` and `Opera`, I'll have my own. For convenience, I put all the code in one file.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class CD {
public:
    string publisher, title, location, year, empty;
public:
    CD()
    {
        publisher = "";
        title = "";
        location = "";
        year = "";
        empty = "";
    }

    void virtual input() = 0;

    void virtual output() = 0;
};


class Popular : public CD
{
public:
    Popular(const string& name)
    {
        title = name;
    }
    virtual void input()
    {
        return;
    }
    virtual void output()
    {
        return;
    }
};

void merge(CD *a[], int, int, int);

void merge_sort(CD *a[], int low, int high) {
    int mid;
    if (low < high) {
        mid = low + (high - low) / 2; //avoid overflow
        merge_sort(a, low, mid);
        merge_sort(a, mid + 1, high);
        merge(a, low, mid, high);
    }
}

void merge(CD *a[], int low, int mid, int high) {

    int p1 = low;
    int p2 = mid + 1;
    CD ** merged = (CD**)malloc(sizeof(CD*) * (high - low + 1)); // CD *b[high] isn't illegal c++ syntax, VLA is part of C99.
    int p = 0;
    while(p1 < mid + 1 && p2 < high + 1)
    {
        if(a[p1]->title > a[p2]->title)
        {
            merged[p] = a[p2];
            p2++;
        }
        else
        {
            merged[p] = a[p1];
            p1++;
        }
        p++;
    }

    while(p1 < mid + 1)
    {
        merged[p++] = a[p1++];
    }

    while(p2 < high + 1)
        merged[p++] = a[p2++];

    for(int i = 0;i < (high - low + 1); i++)
    {
        a[low + i] = merged[i];
    }

    free(merged);
}

int main() {
    CD *cdptr[100]; //pointer declaration for each of our class

    int n = 0, choose;

    // just to test the mergesort
    CD* c1 = new Popular("hello");
    CD* c2 = new Popular("world");
    CD* c3 = new Popular("coldplay");
    CD* c4 = new Popular("pink");

    cdptr[n++] = c1;
    cdptr[n++] = c2;
    cdptr[n++] = c3;
    cdptr[n++] = c4;

    char terminate = 'n'; // you should initialize this variable.

    do // do-while statement which allows the user to enter data and terminate the program when he wants
    {
        cout << "\n1.Classical";
        cout << "\n2.Popular";
        cout << "\n3.Sort";
        cout << "\n4.Display";
        cout << "\n5.Terminate program";
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "\nChoose category: ";
        cin >> choose;
        switch (choose)                            //switch for the user to choose the type of input
        {
            //skip the case 1, 2
            case 3:
                merge_sort(cdptr, 0, n - 1); //  element indices begin at 0.
                break;
            case 4:
                if (n == 0)
                    cout << "\nNo data entered!" << endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    cdptr[i]->output();
                    cout << endl;
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                cout << "\nDo you want to terminate the program? (y/n)";
                cin >> terminate;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "\nNot recognized value!" << endl;
        }
    } while (terminate != 'y');

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        cout<<cdptr[i]->title<<endl;

    delete c1;
    delete c2;
    delete c3;
    delete c4;
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
1.Classical  
2.Popular
3.Sort
4.Display
5.Terminate program


Choose category: 3

1.Classical
2.Popular
3.Sort
4.Display
5.Terminate program


Choose category: 5

Do you want to terminate the program? (y/n)y
coldplay
hello
pink
world
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, update your question to show your real code for `merge`, `merge_sort` and `CD`. I'll be referring to the actual code posted in the comments.

Your problem likely stems from you sorting the titles, as opposed to sorting *based on* the titles. Everywhere in your code where you are assigning the title of a CD to another, you are going wrong. You compare the titles, but you relocate and reorder the objects themselves (or in your case, the pointers to the objects themselves.)

Anyway, to fix this problem you just replace any code like this:

```
x->title = y->title;
```

with this:

```
x = y;
```

For example, instead of

```
b[i]->title = a[h]->title;
```

you should have written

```
b[i] = a[h];
```

By the way, memory allocation and deallocation is not something you do as an afterthought, to see whether it works or not! Even mediocre programmer treat memory with care; the good ones deal with memory with outright love and respect.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for taking time and trying to answer me, the thing is that i havent programmed in C++ for a long long time, and i dont actually remember anything of it, and now i am trying to do something but without any success...

So i have updated the thing as you said, but the program still exits with code error 137, any idea regarding this ?

I would really appreciate it :)